# Do extra Limbs on an Eidolon give them extra weapon attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, summoner

In an upcoming *Pathfinder* campaign, one of my friends that loves to attempt to break games is about to take the [Summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner) class. Out of caution and curiosity, I looked through the advanced evolutions that his character could purchase and got stuck on **Limbs** [as shown around the middle of this page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons#TOC-Limbs-Ex-). The major problem with the rules written as they are is that they give a static BAB for the creature without additional attacks (aside form natural attacks), set a rule where each pair of arms needs an evolution for either a natural attack or an overall weapon profeciency in order to use them in battle, but completely neglect to mention how extra arms wielding weapons work.

In the end, I would like to know this:

**Does having extra limbs give the Eidolon additional weapon attacks, or does it just give it weapon options in a battle without the risk of invoking attacks of opprotunity?**

Comment: What's the relationship between weapon options and attacks of opportunity that you're including AoO in your question?

Comment: @AgentAquarius sheathing a weapon and retrieving a stored item (but not _drawing_ a weapon) both provoke AoO. I suspect that the OP is referring to being able to change weapon without using those actions.

Comment: I think "Limbs" is the least of your concerns if your game-breaker friend is thinking about taking a Summoner...

Comment: @MrLemon well you'd have to work at it and be limited to light weapons am considering a Skiterling Based one for my next character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The [Multi-Weapon Fighting Feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/multiweapon-fighting-combat), has the answers you need.

> Prerequisites: Dex 13, three or more hands.
>
> Benefit: Penalties for fighting with multiple weapons are reduced by –2 with the primary hand and by –6 with off hands.
>
> Normal: A creature without this feat takes a –6 penalty on attacks made with its primary hand and a –10 penalty on attacks made with all of its off hands. (It has one primary hand, and all the others are off hands.) See Two-Weapon Fighting.
>
> Special: This feat replaces the Two-Weapon Fighting feat for creatures with more than two arms.

The 'normal' entry is the only place in the SRD that I can find where fighting with more than two hands and more than two weapons is covered.  The [Two-Weapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Two-Weapon-Fighting) entry in the Combat section is short and refers only to wielding two weapons at once.

Extra attacks from **BAB** are not the same as extra attacks that you get from wielding a second (or third) weapon.  Those apply even if you are multi-wielding (ergo, a 7th level fighter with 4 arms wielding four shortswords with the Multi-Weapon Fighting feat would have 5 attacks - 4 from multi-wielding, calculated using a base attack bonus of 7, and then another from high-BAB, on his primary hand, calculated using a base attack bonus of 2 (7 - 5)).

Notably, the eidolon's limitation on **natural** attacks by RAW does not apply to manufactured weapons, and natural weapons can be used as 'secondary natural attacks' (-5 to hit, 1/2 str bonus to damage) even if your main attack routine is with a manufactured weapon.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Now I must prepare for the possibility of a creature that shoots 11 arrows a round on top of the base abilities an Eidolon.