# Is using multiple Greatswords on an Unchained Eidolon with a Multiweapon Fighting feat worth it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, summoner, pathfinder-society, unchained

My friend plays an Unchained Summoner in Pathfinder Organized Play, and I build a character for them. It's actually possible that I create my own Unchained Summoner two, as I've tried this class already and kinda liked it.

I'd like to maximize overall damage dealt per round. As my Google-Fu shows, most people speaking about Eidolons give them either a lot of Natural Attack or build them for archery. However, I would like to try a (possibly) even more damaging thing.

I'd like to give an Azata several pairs of Limbs (arms) as it progresses, and make the said Azata wield a Greatsword in each pair of limbs. [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/71758/30214) says that there is a special feat for that called [Multiweapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/multiweapon-fighting-combat).

The earliest point when this feat can be taken is level 3: you cannot qualify when you are level 1.

**Will this actually give a better damage per round than a natural attacks-based build?**

**Is the same possible with multiple bows used in each pair of limbs?**

**If it's worth it at some point, does it always stay powerful?**

PFS rules are used, hence it's not important what happens after character level 12.

Comment: Considering the PFS tag, to the best of my knowledge Multiweapon Fighting is not legal in PFS per [Additional Resources](https://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/rpg/additional)

Comment: None of the feats from Bestiary 1 are legal for play for PCs, animal companions, or familiars unless specifically granted by another legal source; And Eidolons don't have anything that would grant them the feat ( unlike Animal Companions who explicitly get access to Improved Natural Attack and such).

Comment: Eidolons are neither of PCs, animal companions, or familiars; they are summoned creatures.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

At level 3 you will have a base melee to-hit of +7 (3BAB + 3STR + 1bonus, not counting any feats or other build-agnostic enhancements). With extra pair of limbs and Slam evolution for them you get 2x claws +7 (1d4+4) from base biped form and 2x slams +7 (1d8+4).

With 2x greatswords you get two attacks at +3 (2d6+6). Both to-hit and sum of damage are lower.

I haven't tried building it any further, but I suspect the natural attack build will get even further apart as you go.

Similar thing would happen with bows, even worse with eidolon's Dex being a 4 lower for extra -2 to-hit.

Comment: Wait, is it possible to have both a Slam and a pair of Claws on one pair of limbs?

Comment: No. Bipeds start with a pair of limbs and 2x claw attacks for free. At third level you get 3 evolution points, enough to get a second pair of hands (2ep) and get Slam for them (1ep).

Comment: I have created [a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88923/discussion-of-eidolons-optimization) to discuss this build so we don't flood the comments. I have come up with some interesting ideas that I would like to present and discuss with you.